# play framework 2.1 with tomcat 7

Tags: mysql, tomcat7, playframework-2.1

I have just used Play Framework WAR plugin together with Maven plugin and create a WAR file and I got the following exception while deploying to Tomcat:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1597)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData.getTables(DatabaseMetaData.java:4997)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.isConnectionHandleAlive(BoneCP.java:677)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionTesterThread.run(ConnectionTesterThread.java:103)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:165)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

I am using `application.conf` in Play Framework to insert my connection info.

Anybody can help me on this issue?

Comment: Is your database driver on the classpath?